# Justifications for excluding a data point

Tags: statistics

To whom it may concern,
I would like to know the justifications than can be used to exclude a data point from a dataset? I eliminate one country from my dataset because the value of this country was far from the other countries.
Yours Faithfully,
Bahareh Shojaie

Comment: Google "outlier"?

Comment: I have. I found a reference: Rousseeuw, P. J., & Hubert, M. (2011). Robust statistics for outlier detection. Wiley Interdisciplinary Reviews: Data Mining and Knowledge Discovery, 1(1), 73-79. But I am not sure how it can be applicable to my research.

Comment: Well, without more information on what your research *is*, it's impossible to say...

Comment: This country (Japan) has a distinctive reason for its high number, and these reasons are not included in my scope. The value is around 7000,which is distinctive from other countries. The second country's value is around 2000. And actually 2/3 of the total numbers belong to this country: Japan. My supervisor agrees with me to eliminate this country, but I need a justification

Answer (score 1):

An outlier does not justify being eliminated from a data set (e.g., it could be from a Pareto distribution). A confirmed measurement or instrument error could be an acceptable reason, but then why could the property not be measured again?

Comment: This country (Japan) has a distinctive reason for its high number, and these reasons are not included in my scope. The value is around 7000,which is distinctive from other countries. The second country's value is around 2000. And actually 2/3 of the total numbers belong to this country: Japan. My supervisor agrees with me to eliminate this country, but I need a justification .